# Uncaught Error: Class 'yii\web\Application' when debug frontend/web/index in Yii2

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, localhost

I have some problems when I'm try to access my application. If I access my app using port 8000, for example: `localhost:8000` in browser it just returns 404 Not Found with message like this : **The requested resource / was not found on this server.**. Then, if try access my app using localhost/nameapp it success return first page default of my app but css, js can't be read.

I'm try to debug index.php in frontend/web like this :

```
<?php
var_dump(new  yii\web\Application());

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php';

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php'
);

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

it return error like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'yii\web\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\nameapp\frontend\web\index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\nameapp\frontend\web\index.php on line 2
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You're trying to instantiate `\yii\web\Application` before you loaded (included) any library/autoloader.

Comment: You are trying to call var_dump before it's loaded. If you really must debug it with such terrible way do it after the `Yii.php` is required in this file.

Comment: I'm try to move var_dump right before (new yii\web\Application($config))->run(); then it returns: ```Fatal error: Uncaught yii\base\InvalidConfigException: The "id" configuration for the Application is required. in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php:220 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(202): yii\base\Application->preInit(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\frontend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php on line 220``` what's wrong?

Comment: You must set `id` in your `config.php` - https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-configurations#application-configurations